# Add Aspect To Asset in MindSphere

Tags: mindsphere

I am using the MindSphere JAVA SDK (1.0.0). I have an asset and I created an Aspect. 
How can I assign the existing aspect to the existing asset in java?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow is always:

- create the aspect
- add the aspect to an assettype
- create an instance asset of this assettype

If you want to update an asset, you just have to add the aspect to the related assettype.